# Avoid undeleting corrupted/partially overwritten files

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, forensics

Recently I dealt with some computers infected by ransomware, with encrypted user files. My job was to either decrypt these files (if possible), or recover as much usable files as possible. That included also undeleting files from NTFS partition images.

Of course I already knew "foremost" and "ntfsundelete" tools, and I used them before for other tasks. However now I have a problem with them.

The problem is that both of these tools attempt to recover all possible files, including ones, that are already overwritten (either partially of completely). This behaviour is probably very useful in a forensics lab, where even small parts of images/movies/documents can be treated as evidence. However in my use case, my customers are interested in getting back only fully restored files, and don't have time to pick them from thousands of corrupted ones.

(I also know that ntfsundelete has -p switch, but it doesn't work sufficiently in many cases.)

So, my question is, what is the most time-effective method to perform automatic recovery of deleted files from NTFS partitions, avoiding restoring corrupted/overwritten files?

Comment: This question seems to be about undeleting files and not infosec. The fact that the problem arose due to a ransomware virus isn't relevant to what is asked. I'm voting to migrate this question to SuperUser.

Comment: "what is the best method" - opinion based. Please reword your question to keep it open.

Comment: There are numerous tools for recovering files from NTFS, some of these will rate files according to their "recoverability" such as "excellent" for files that have not been overwritten and something less for files that may be corrupted. You can just mark all the ones with the "excellent" rating and recover those only. You would need to find a program that has this functionality.

Comment: ntfsundelete has this functionality. The problem is that it fails in many cases, because it is based only on NTFS indexes, instead of real validation of recovered data. A few years ago I tried to recover some data from SD card using some Windows-based software, made especially for recovering photos, and it displayed thumbnails of recovered photos for manual verification - so realtime validation is possible. What I need now, is a similar software, that would be scriptable and would allow time-effective bulk recovery (disk after disk, whole directory structure at once).